# Save a Single Sheet in Google Sheets as PDF using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to save just the active sheet as a pdf when clicking the save pdf button. Currently my code saves all of the sheets. How should I edit this code?

```html
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Save PDF", functionName:"saveAsPDF"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Save as PDF', submenu);  
}

function saveAsPDF() {
  const folderName = `social`;
  const fileNamePrefix = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a1').getValue();
  const PhasePrefix = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a2').getValue();
  
  var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();


   DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
    .next()
    .createFile(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getBlob()
                  .getAs(`application/pdf`)
                  .setName(`${fileNamePrefix} - ${PhasePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), `GMT-8`, `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`));  

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.alert('New PDF file created in ' + folderName )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, be careful as the save as pdf option is going away in December. I'm not sure if this will affect the script function, but you'll get a warning when trying it manually. worth checking out...
(not tested)

save as pdf goes to the folder and saves the file. if you're already in the file, you just want to save one sheet, you probably don't need to go and grab the whole file.

I was going to write this up, but I think this link will do what you want best.
https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/

Scroll down to the Source Code section.
You're looking for this function 'exportCurrentSheetAsPDF'

```
function exportCurrentSheetAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  
  var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), currentSheet)
  _exportBlob(blob, currentSheet.getName(), spreadsheet)
}
```

This has the simple excerpt. I do encourage you to go to give them clicks and there's lots of other good stuff there. I think that is probably more than you wanted, but maybe things you didn't know you wanted...

Comment: Hello, where did you read that "save as pdf" is being deprecated?

Comment: I misspoke. I meant save to google drive (as pdf). sorry for the confusion.